# How to make div disappear on hover, and another appear?

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

I want to have 2 divs with opacity. One that is present, and one that is present, when a. is hovered. -> Due to the opacity, the first div needs to disappear as to not be visible, when the second appears.

I tried doing this:

```
<div id="box">
    <a href="#" class="infobox">Hover me<div class="HideNseek">This is hidden.</div></a>
</div>

#box {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    height: 480px;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 120px;
}
a.infobox {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.infobox div.HideNseek {
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
a.infobox:hover div.HideNseek {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    height: 480px;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top: -34px;
}
```

How to make the first div disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery -

```
$('.infobox').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent('div').hide();
});
```

To make it reappear:

```
$('.infobox').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent('div').hide();
},function(){
   $(this.parent('div').show())
});
```

Comment: I am absolutely horrible with jQuery, putting this in does make the div disappear, however the second div does not appear? +the first div stays hidden, whereas I need it to reappear again.

Comment: Of course not. The second is a child of the first. If you want to hide the first, the contents therein will be hidden.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reappear when the hover is off - note that when the div disappears, the :hover will no longer apply. You need to rethink the div structure for this to work.